# difficult to identify (visually) the difference between answered questions and accepted answered question

Tags: feature-request

When I want to look for the new unanswered questions (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?filter=need-answers), the questions which has answers and which has accepted answers are shown as in this image.

[image: image showing answered and accepted answered questions]

But the difference is subtle. It is more harder if they are not near. (to compare and differentiate). Can we change the way accepted answered questions are displayed. Rather than changing the text to yellow, can we change it some other color which would make it easier to identify. Or a tick mark near to the number.

I use flux to reduce the blue intensity which makes it much harder to identify this difference.

Comment: In my opinion the difference is very obvious.

Comment: @MarounMaroun If it is that obvious, i wouldn't have taken this time and effort to ask this question!

Comment: That's why I said *in my opinion* - I'm curious to know if others agree with me, and that's why I posted my comment.

Comment: I don't find it clear either. Mainly the white color on green and the yellow color on green.

Comment: I think it's deliberately subtle. When searching for a solution, whether or not the user who asked the question clicked accept is not all that important. It's there if you care enough to look for it, but not obnoxiously in your face.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is pretty obvious, but only when you "look at it", but when when scanning a list of questions you just see a green block and the difference isn't that obvious (not for me anyway).

It's been like this for a very long time, and I doubt it'll change any time soon − if ever. But not all is lost, since you can easily change this with a user script (or even just user css):

```
$('.status.answered-accepted').css({'background-color': '#0f0', color: '#333'})
```